# using Swift's self in Javascript to access Swift class variables and functions

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I have a project in which I call a JS method `function jsMethod(selfRef)` from Swift class. Lets assume, we have a `class A` from which this method is called. `selfRef` is reference to `self`, i.e. when called from `class A` `selfRef` will hold reference to `self` of `class A`

How can I use this `selfRef` to access a variable or call a method in `class A`

Comment: Where are you executing your javascript?  Are you using a `WKWebview` or `JavaScriptCore`?

Comment: JavaScriptCore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send only those objects to JS which have been derived from NSObject. If your class A does not inherit from NSObject, it won't work as is. You may try one of the following approaches:

1. **Convert class to struct**: You can pass any primitive type and hence struct is supported.
2. **Inherit from NSObject**: Make your class A inherit from NSObject. Though you might lose the "swiftness" of swift but this won't matter for most of the applications. (The swift classes don't inherit from NSObject for a reason but that is a discussion for a different question.)
3. **Wrap the object**: Write an adapter (or in simple terms - a wrapper) for your Swift class and send the adapter to JS. The adapter should inherit NSObject. This will keep the character and performance of Swift in the swift code as the change will only be at the layer which interacts with JS. JS would call methods on the original object through the corresponding functions in the adapter. Don't try to pull the original object from the wrapper in JS as it will result in a crash.